# How to override rule(parser) exception from grammar file (.g) in antlr4.5

Tags: python, antlr4

I'm trying to avoid reporting an error (and recovering) during execution of MyParser.py. How to adapt this example of exception overriding (from antlr4 book) for python targets:

```
 rule : ...
    ;
    catch[RecognitionException e] {throw e;}
```

Looks like, using something like:

```
rule : SOMEDIGIT {print("This guy"); };
except [RecognitionException re] {print ("Everyone happy");}
```

produce an error:

```
syntax error: '{print ("Everyone happy");}' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble
```

PS. I'm using antlr4-python2-runtime-4.5